# what is an efficient way to load and aggregate a large .bz2 file into pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to load a large bz2 file in chunks and aggregate into a pandas DataFrame, but Python keeps crashing. The methodology I'm using is below, which I've had success with on smaller datasets. What is a more efficient way to aggregate larger than memory files into Pandas?

Data is line delimited json compressed to bz2, taken from https://files.pushshift.io/reddit/comments/ (all publicly available reddit comments).

```
import pandas as pd
reader = pd.read_json('RC_2017-09.bz2', compression='bz2', lines=True, chunksize=100000) df = pd.DataFrame() for chunk in reader:
    # Count of comments in each subreddit
    count = chunk.groupby('subreddit').size()
    df = pd.concat([df, count], axis=0)
    df = df.groupby(df.index).sum() 
    reader.close()
```

EDIT: Python crashed when I used chunksize 1e5. The script worked when i increased chunksize to 1e6.

Comment: If the file is larger than memory, then there will be no way to load it all into a pandas dataframe at once since that would be all in memory. Instead, you'll need to use a library like `dask` which lazily loads a dataset, allowing you to perform computations on files larger than memory. In particular, you'll want to take a look at [Dask DataFrames](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html)

Comment: I've looked into dask a ilttle bit, but had trouble making it work with this file. What I'm trying to do here isn't to load the entire file into memory at one time, but to add a chunk of it into memory, aggregate the chunk, store the aggregated piece into "df", and repeat. So at the end I would have aggregated the entire dataset into "df", without ever having the entire dataset in memory at one time

Comment: In that case your approach might work. Do you know how large each aggregated dataframe is in comparison to the chunks? It is possible the aggregation is still larger than can fit in memory?

Comment: So I think I figured it out. Using chunksize = 1e5 would cause Python to eventually crash, but increasing the chunksize to 1e6 seemed to work, just took a while. I'm not sure of the mechanics behind why that is, but apparently my chunksize was too small relative to the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I used this iterator method which work for me without memory error. you can try it.

```
chunksize = 10 ** 6
cols=['a','b','c','d']
iter_csv = pd.read_csv(filename.bz2, compression='bz2', delimiter='\t', usecols=cols, low_memory=False, iterator=True, chunksize=chunksize, encoding="utf-8")
# some work related to your group by replacing below code
df = pd.concat([chunk[chunk['b'] == 1012] for chunk in iter_csv])
```